# Section and subsection numbers not being shown when compiling in Linux

Tags: sectioning, numbering, miktex, texlive

I am writing a document on LaTex and when I compile on my Windows computer (using Miktex) I see correctly the section, subsection, and subsubsection numbers, as shown in this figure:
[image]

However, when I compile exactly the same files on my Ubuntu computer (with TeX Live), the section numbers do not appear:

[image]

This is an example of the document with the problem:

```
\documentclass{dissertation}
\begin{document}
\section{Example 1}
\subsection{Example 1.1}
\subsubsection{Example 1.1.1}
\subsubsection{Example 1.1.2}
\subsection{Example 1.2}
\subsubsection{Example 1.2.1}
\subsubsection{Example 1.2.2}
\end{document}
```

and this is my `dissertation.cls` file:

```
\LoadClass[10pt]{book}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
```

This is the output that I get with the above example:
[image]

Lastly, this is my log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.11.19)  17 DEC 2019 12:00
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**stackoverflow.tex
(./stackoverflow.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 31 language(s) loaded.
(./dissertation.cls (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2016/02/24 3.9q The Babel package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2016/02/24 3.9q Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
Package: titlesec 2016/03/15 v2.10.1 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box26
\beforetitleunit=\skip43
\aftertitleunit=\skip44
\ttl@plus=\dimen104
\ttl@minus=\dimen105
\ttl@toksa=\toks14
\titlewidth=\dimen106
\titlewidthlast=\dimen107
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen108
)
(./stackoverflow.aux)
\openout1 = `stackoverflow.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
 [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

]
(./stackoverflow.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 924 strings out of 494333
 11362 string characters out of 6163938
 68727 words of memory out of 5000000
 4315 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 5511 words of font info for 20 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 372 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 30i,4n,29p,207b,155s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl10.pfb>
Output written on stackoverflow.pdf (1 page, 37244 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 24 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 16 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: If you want others to help then please post a self contained minimal example that others can test as is.  Note that packages like `geometry`, `graphicx` and `hyperref` are capable of automatically detecting the needed driver, so that if-else stack is not needed.

Comment: please don't post disconnected fragments that we can not test, make a small complete document (including a section heading) and show the output that you get _from the test document)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for your comment. I will now post my full cls file and a mock document

Comment: are you using pdflatex or xelatex, in the xelatex code path you are using several fonts that are only licenced for use on windows eg CambriaMath  so they will not be available in linux

Comment: Once I removed the diagrams package (shouldn't really be used due to its license), I have no issues with it (I did merge it into a single document as David requested). I have 1, 1.1 and 1.2 numbered (NB: I used pdflatex)

Comment: @cholo14 to make it easier for people to help you should really delete everything from the class file that is unrelated to the problem. It is easy for you to test after deleting things that the problem is still there. I would guess that you used xelatex and simply do not have the fonts, but in that case you would have had errors from the system telling you the fonts were not available

Comment: I still have the same issue even when removing the diagrams package. The issue is there with pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, and latex

Comment: can you delete the reference to diagrams so we can run the example, and show the log you get on the test document with pdflatex

Comment: I updated the question deleting the parts of the cls file that are not needed. I still have the same issue. @DavidCarlisle the log file is 1800 lines long. Should I add a link to it or are there specific parts that I should post here?

Comment: does your log  have any `missing character` errors also ypur log woul dbe a lot shorter if you deleted all the packages from the class file not relevant eg I assume you can detelte tikz and algorithm and  fancyheader and... while still showing theproblem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have removed all the useless packages as requested and now provided a minimalistic example. I have also posted the log file. The problem seems to be ``titlesec`` package, if I remove it I see the section and subsection numbers (but no subsubsection numbers)

Comment: OK so there is the difference you have a 2016 titlesec but I have `Package: titlesec 2019/10/16 v2.13 Sectioning titles`  (when you get numbered sections but not subsections) you have a rather old (2015) distribution but you could get a titlesec.sty from your windows machine and put it in the same directory as your document

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle! That was indeed the issue. I updated ``titlesec.sty`` and now it works perfectly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments by updating a package.